# PHPStorm colon instead of curly braces

Tags: if-statement, phpstorm, indentation

I just purchased PHPStorm and while writing and if statement i realized that PHPStorm wants me to write an if statement like this WITH braces: if($value == $value2){}; I want to use colon instead after the if statement is that possible like this. if($value1 == $value2): endif;

Ive tried several things to make it work... It just seems that they don't support colon after statements... I hope you clever guys has the answer... Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it NOT the correct PHP Syntax?

Comment: And I'm sure JetBrain supporters would be happy to support you and would be much mỏe responsive that StackOverflow!